# Random emails missing from IMAP inbox with Apple Mail in Yosemite

Tags: macos, mail.app, email, imap

I am using Apple Mail with three IMAP mail accounts (not Gmail etc. but from my hosting provider).

I'm finding that I regularly need to close and reopen Mail to find emails I'm searching for that are not showing up in the inbox. They reappear after the restart where I expect them to be. Not the biggest issue but it's happening a lot.

What is causing this?

Comment: Most likely not your device.  An IMAP inbox is a server side folder that synches with your device, the problem is likely the hosting providers.

Comment: When you click the "get mail" button at the top left of the window, do they appear like if you do a restart?

Comment: Thanks both. Kevin, its just the odd email. I was looking for a message I knew I had received but it wasn't in the inbox or coming up in a search. When I restarted the application it was there. It had been there previously as well. Odd

Comment: Is there a issue with size or the amount of emails downloads? do you have lots of Rules ? Is the lost email in the "Archive" folder?

Comment: It may happen that the mailbox index got screwed up.  Have you tried rebuilding the mailbox(es)?  In case you did not, here is how: Select the mailbox you want to rebuild, then click on menu "Mailbox" > "Rebuild".  In many cases, that can solve issues like that.

Comment: Hi Buscar - Only a couple of rules relating to an account that hasn't been effected and simply to forward to another account. Size shouldn't be an issue. I have it set to only sync attachments when asked. I'll check for Archive next time it happens. But don't think they were there.

Comment: Phoenix. Thanks. I will try rebuilding. But would that create/solve an ad-hoc, random issue? My wife incidentally suffers the same on her Mac. With accounts from the same host. Typing that makes mw think I need to flag it with them.

Comment: @ChrisCallander I've seen the same issue for years now.  Using Gmail IMAP, so it probably isn' the hosting provider.  I've looked through settings, but don't see anything that says to delete emails, yet they are being deleted locally. (using gmail web interface always works perfectly to find them)